# How to set raspberry pi gpio to low at boot (PWM pins)

Tags: gpio, boot, pwm

I have project that works with raspberry pi 3 which control a motor speed through PWM0 pin (GPIO 19), **the problem is that raspberry pi give high state after startup** , which cause the spinning of the motor at low speed ( because the PWM is giving low duty_cycle value ) ,**i want to avoid this by making PWM0 pin (GPIO 19) give low state during booting and after start** ,that will prevent the motor from start spinning , unless i started its script that will give the PWM0 high state .

Comment: Try writing in sentences. Without some idea what you have actually done it is difficult to work out what you are asking.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

GPIO 19 will never be high and will not be a output unless you do something to make it so.

All pins are initially configured as inputs with either pullup or pulldown; in this case GPIO 19 is configured as input with pulldown.

NOTE again GPIO 19 is **NOT** a "PWM0 pin" and won't unless you configure it.

You can configure a pin shortly after boot, using the `gpio` option in `config.txt`, but this would be a sledgehammer approach to solve whatever is actually wrong.

Comment: Thank you for your reply , I forget that i forced this gpio to be output , using (sudo nano /etc/rc.local) , now I removed what I wrote and it works , now the gpio 19 not sending any thing after start , But after activating PWM at GPIO 19 using (sudo nano /boot/config.txt) it becomes neither Output nor Input ,it is ALT5 that's what the (gpio readall ) command gave me as a result , and the problem appear again the PWM is sending signal after startup .